# Create directory recursively in python for linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am trying to create directory recursively using a Python script, but am getting and error.

#### Code:

```
import os
a = "abc"
os.makedirs('/root/test_{}'.format(a), exist_ok=True)
```

#### Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "mk.py", line 3, in <module>
>     os.makedirs('/root/test_{}'.format(a), exist_ok=True)
>   TypeError: makedirs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'
> ```

I am using python2.7 and the above option does not work in this version? If not, what is alternate solution?

Comment: `exist_ok` is "new" in version 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) is the correct function, but is has no parameter `exist_ok` in Python 2.  Instead use [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) like:

```
if not os.path.exists(path_to_make):
    os.makedirs(path_to_make)
```

Be aware that this does not exactly match the bahavior of the `exist_ok` flag in Python3.  Closer to matching that would be something like:

```
if os.path.exists(path_to_make):
    if not os.path.isdir(path_to_make):
        raise OSError("Cannot create a file when that file already exists: "
                      "'{}'".format(path_to_make))
else:
    os.makedirs(path_to_make)
```

Comment: No, this has not the same behaviour.

Comment: @wim, Really?  Why not?  What am I missing?

Comment: For example if a file with the name exists (not a directory).

Comment: @wim, this look better?

Comment: Doesn't that check technically get applied to every part of the path.

Comment: Yes, but that is OK, because it is just trying to verify that something else does not already exist at that name this is not a directory.

Comment: This code has a race condition (another process could execute a system call between the system calls from this process to check for existence and for creating an entry). A more robust approach is to just attempt to create eaoh directory, and catch the error for "directory already exists". Handling "name exists but isn't a directory" is an interesting challenge.